# How to query data from database from using query string values

Tags: mysql, laravel

As a beginner I don't know how to go about this. I have the following method in my controller.

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {


        if (request(['condition','make','model','year'])) {
            $vehicles = Vehicle::where('condition', $request->condition)
                ->where('make', $request->make)
                ->where('model', $request->model)
                ->where('year', $request->year)

                ->paginate(20);
        } else {
            $vehicles = Vehicle::paginate(20);
        }



        $conditions = DB::table("conditions")->pluck("name","id");
        return view('cars',compact('conditions', 'vehicles'));
    }
```

Now I'd like it to be in a way that if I only have a condition value from the request e.g new then I can see new vehicles only on searching. As of now it only works when all the values of the keys are provided!

Comment: Did you try replacing `if (request(['condition','make','model','year'])) {` with `if ($request->has('condition')) {`?

Comment: @KazikM the result is still the same. When the all the values of condition, make, model and year are provided then I get the vehicles with those properties but when I provide only one value of the keys then no result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the $request has the keys

Try

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = Vehicle::query();
    
    if($request->has('condition')) {
        $query->where('condition', $request->condition);
    }

    if($request->has('make')){
        $query->where('make', $request->make);
    }
    
    if($request->has('model')) {
        $query->where('model', $request->model);
    }

    if($request->has('year')){
        $query->where('year', $request->year);
    }

    $vehicles = $query->paginate(20);

    $conditions = DB::table("conditions")->pluck("name","id");

    return view('cars',compact('conditions', 'vehicles'));

}
```

Comment: getting `syntax error, unexpected ';'` at the end of each `where method` and after removing them I get `syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)'`

Comment: Sorry my bad had some typos in syntax - missing closing parenthesis in the if conditions - fixed that in the answer

Comment: No error now but still working same as before!

Comment: I don't get "still working same as before"? Can you pls elaborate

Comment: My original code when the all the keys have vulues i.e `locallhost//cars?condition=new&make=Subaru&model=Impreza&year=2030&price=allPrices` then I'll be able to query the car with those properties but when I try to provide only one value from my dropdown e.g condition to be equal to new from the drop down which has two options(new and used) then I don't get back the new cars... I get nothing back. That is what I mean by before. 

Goal is to fetch new cars if I only provide one key value in the request

Comment: Can't be. Just try to `dd($vehicles->paginate(20)` in the index method before returning the view. Then refresh the page with just one query param `?condition=new` and check the output of dd()

Comment: It's working now, I had a mistake in my select tags. They were grabbing default values that are not on my table when not selected. So when I selected New label the condition key value would be `new` and `new` is in the condition column in the vehicle table but make  key when not selected would have a value that's not in the make column in the table.  I've fixed it and now it's working well as expected!

Answer (score 1):

You have to check each `$request` key separately.
You can leverage the `when()` eloquent method to have a fluent query. No need the if / else anymore. Here is the full method rewriten:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {

     $vehicles = Vehicle::when($request->input('condition'), function ($query, $condition)
    {
       return $query->where('condition',$condition);
    })->when($request->input('make'), function ($query, $make)
    {
       return  $query->where('make',$make);
    })->when($request->input('model'), function ($query, $model)
    {
       return  $query->where('model', $model);
    })->when($request->input('year'), function ($query, $year)
    {
       return  $query->where('year', $year);
    })->paginate(20);

        $conditions = DB::table("conditions")->pluck("name","id");
        return view('cars',compact('conditions', 'vehicles'));
    }
```

`when()` method doc reference https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: working same way as before after implementing this!

Comment: sorry, i forgot to put the `return`. Please re-check with the modified code

Comment: Still working same as before after the change

Comment: It's working now, I had a mistake in my select tags. They were grabbing default values that are not on my table when not selected. So when I selected New label the condition key value would be `new` and `new` is in the condition column in the vehicle table but make  key when not selected would have a value that's not in the make column in the table.  I've fixed it and now it's working well as expected!

Answer (score 0):

To filter any rows from a table by multiple conditions, that needs some logical operator or operand. Assuming the query object has proper injection validation, then simply you can use OR operator.

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::where('condition', $request->condition ?: '')
                ->orWhere('make', $request->make ?: '')
                ->orWhere('model', $request->model ?: '')
                ->orWhere('year', '=', $request->year ?: 007)

                ->paginate(20)
```

Hope this could helps.

Comment: This won't work because if say $request->model is not present then it will try to match the records where model has a value of empty string which is not what is intended

Comment: Also if multiple query params are present the query will return unintended results due to orWhere

Comment: Of course you can make some customizing by actual logical you needs. However your first comment is wrong, I think. And your second comment is related on my comment means depending on your actual needs. For all satisfied condition, of course that needs AND logical.

Comment: Say if the query has just `?year=2010` then `where('condition', $request->condition ?:  '')` will look for all records where the value of `condition` column is an empty string, where as in actual condition column has either  "new" or "used" as value. so the query will ignore all rows where the value of condition column is not empty string which means it will not return any rows

Comment: Understood. Simply you can use "LIKE" operator, and use "%" as the default condition.